# Ubuntu Versions in Login loop even the terminal window

Tags: command-line, login, mate

I have tried installing various versions of ubuntu on Udoo board but each time after installation the operating system ends up in a login loop even the terminal window launched after the combination of `ctrl+alt+f3` is also stuck in the loop.I believe that this might seem to be a duplicate question at once but in each scenario for all the users in nearly all the questions at least the terminal seems to work fine for login. Also I have tested the compatibility of the os with the SBC by installing it on an other same board and everything works fine. I have tried installing ubuntu 18.04,16.04,ubuntu mate 18.04 and 16.04 but each time the result seems the same.however things seem to work fine in the guest mode for mate.

Comment: could you provide details on your hardware? did it ever work before? does windows work now? when did it stop working? what did you notice changed before it started not working?

Comment: Udoo X86, Yes windows does,even Ubuntu MATE works fine in live boot mode but fails once installed.

Comment: continue. as is that just won't be enough information to go on.

Comment: what else may I get you as I see no error message even in the terminal.

Comment: could you provide details on your hardware? did it ever work before? when did it stop working? what did you notice changed before it started not working?

Comment: its a fresh install, but ubuntu unity seems to work on an other same board, and on this board too. so even if you could suggest me a proper and efficient way to migrate to Ubuntu MATE from unity it would be great.

Comment: `sudo apt install mate-desktop`

Comment: I do not need just the UI there are some devices with drivers compatible just with mate so need the packages too that are in mate.

Comment: well then that's not something I know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue happened with me few months back. Issue was with my current user through which I was trying to login. I logged into a single user mode and created a new user and try log in using new user which solved my issue. I know it's a hack but it worked :)

P.S. I'm not sure about the exact reason why it was failing with old user and working with new one.

Comment: Thanks !! That saved long efforts as I was using a username that belonged to a driver name too and as the result it was creating issues while login, but I still fail to understand why was I allowed by operating system to create such username then ??